# How to insert only one value into sqlite3 table as an variable while inserting null to every else column

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, insert

I want to modify the code beneath so that I only insert `input` variable to the table. All other columns should store `NULL` value. I think the most obvious solution would be to declare that `column2 = NULL` and `column3 = NULL`, but I was thinking is there another way?

```
import sqlite3

column1 = input()

sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()

sqlite_insert_with_param = "INSERT INTO ideas (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (?, ?, ?);" #column1 is primary key

data_tuple = (column1, column2, column3)
cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_with_param, data_tuple)
sqliteConnection.commit()

cursor.close()
```

Eventually I want this to work in Tkinter app that prompts user input for column 1 with `Entry`-widget and it would create the database entry without any other information on it other than the primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the other columns from the list, like:

```
sqlite_insert_with_param = "INSERT INTO ideas (column1) VALUES (?);"
data_tuple = (column1,)
cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_with_param, data_tuple)
sqliteConnection.commit()
```

then `column2` and `column3` will be `null` in the new inserted row, unless you have defined a default value for them in the definition of the table.